# Pattern tokenizer in elasticsearch splitting on white space and special character

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created an analyzer in elasticsearch as follows.

```
   {
    "analyzer": {
        "pattern_analyzers": {
            "type": "custom",
            "pattern": ",",
            "tokenizer": "pattern"
        }
    }
}
```

Added the same analyzer to a string field, where I store values as comma separated.
The value for the field will be like say,

```
"skills":"software-engineer,hardware,android developer"
```

Here I am not getting the exact result, as want to get is like it should split only when it encounters comma. What result I am getting currently is, the string splits on whitespace and special characters.

How to modify my analyzer to make it split the string only when it encounters a comma.

**EDIT:**

In scenarios like this `"software,Engineer (Core, Non-IT),hardware"`
It shouldnot split like `"software","Engineer (Core"," Non-IT)","hardware"`

Instead of `"software","Engineer (Core, Non-IT)","hardware"`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a right way of making a custom analyzer
Try doing it this way.

PUT my_index

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "pattern_analyzers": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is working. But in some scenarios it needs improvement like this, In this case "software,Engineer (Core, Non-IT),hardware", it shouldn't split the inner ,

Comment: Right for that you have to modify your regex and choosing the appropriate group which you want to be indexed. Here is the link to this.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html